# pjax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, history.js, pjax

I have a trouble with the pjax .

I download the lastest pjax at https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

then i code as the demo, but it doesn't work.
the main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>main.html</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/plugin/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(window.document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
        Go to <a href="MyHtml.html">next page</a>.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the MyHtml.html as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MyHtml.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is my HTML page. <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i clicked on the link, it forward to MyHtml.html directly. is there any problem with my code?

i can just sure that the pjax has worked something, when i click the back button to main.html, it back to another page which i used before main.html.

Comment: You aren't following the jquery-pjax instructions.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the content of `MyHtml.html`?

Comment: MyHtml.html just a hello world page.no script or meta .only 'hello world' in the body.

Comment: i follow the jquery-pjax instructions either.but it doesn't work,and someone else tells to do like the demo.

Comment: Without a demo URL and without the up-to-date code for your pages, all I can do is guess. Do you want to keep guessing until something works, or do you want to really understand?

Comment: sorry,i'm lack to desciption a question in english .i have modified the content and post the two demo pages,could you find anything wrong?thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry,it doesn't work with the code you have post neither.and another question is that all my pages need to include the same content such as script and meta? it's hard to maintain it if so.when i want to add a new nav ,every page should be modified .is there any other measure?

Comment: Update the code in your question (or provide a demo URL) before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: i updated the code everytime ,and viewed many pages,tried a lot measures to make it  work, but i failed. can the code work in your environment?

Comment: What I meant was edit the question so it shows what code you are using right now. The code I provided works for me.

Comment: What particular "jquery-pjax instructions" @miles is not following?

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using static HTML pages you will need the `fragment` option. Your pjax config should probably be:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container', { 
        fragment: '#pjax-container', 
        timeout: 3000 
    });
});
```

Also, all your pages will need to have similar markup, with only the content of `#pjax-container` being different. The content of `#pjax-container` should be the only thing that changes between pages. 
Your `MyHtml.html` page should probably be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MyHtml.html</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/plugin/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container', { 
        fragment: '#pjax-container', 
        timeout: 3000 
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <div id="pjax-container">
      This is my HTML page. <br />
      Go to the <a href="main.html">main page</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did it like yours,but didn't work .it fresh the full page.may i email you?

Comment: sorry,i have not a demo url.i copied the demo which was the pjax supported.but it didn't work neither. and there's no errors in chrome's console.

Comment: Where do you see the following requirement? 
"all your pages will need to have similar markup, with only the content of #pjax-container being different"